# Terminate Python Process and halt it's underlying os.system command line

Tags: python, windows

I am running a script that launches a program via cmd and then, while the program is open, checks the log file of the program for errors. If any, close the program.

I cannot use `taskkill` command since I don't know the PID of the process and the image is the same as other processes that I don't want to kill.

Here is a code example:

```
import os, multiprocessing, time

def runprocess():
    os.system('"notepad.exe"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=runprocess,args=[])
    process.start()
    time.sleep(5)

    #Continuously checking if errors in log file here...
    process_has_errors = True #We suppose an error has been found for our case.

    if process_has_errors:
        process.terminate()
```

The problem is that I want the notepad windows to close. It seems like the `terminate()` method will simply disconnect the process without closing all it's tasks.

What can I do to make sure to end all pending tasks in a process when terminating it, instead of simply disconnecting the process from those tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `taskkill` but you have to use the `/T` (and maybe `/F`) switch so all child processes of the cmd process are killed too. You get the process id of the cmd task via `process.pid`.

Comment: That's it. I also must say that I found the way to find the process PID, by using `pid = process.pid` in my code. Then, this pid is added to a command looking like `os.system('"taskkill /pid ' + str(pid) + ' /F /T"')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a system call if you know the name of the process:

```py
import os
...
    if process_has_errors:
        processName = "notepad.exe"
        process.terminate()
        os.system(f"TASKKILL /F /IM {processName}")
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use the image of the process since there are other processes that I don't want to close with the same image. But I definitely believe this will help others that doesn't have this constraint.

Comment: Im sorry that i was not able to help you but Im glad you found a solution!